# How to trap system errors in ( Mathematica ) MUnit?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Background:

I wrote a test for a new class ( in OO System for Mathematica ). I ran the test using Workbench and I expected a failure in the MUnit test-report because the class does not exist yet ( test first, code later method ).

The test is:

```
 Test[
     clist = loadClass["UList"]         
     ,
     Class["UList`"]
     ,
     TestID->"UListTest-20110730-loadClass"
 ]
```

MUnit gave no report at all, MUnit did not get control, it ended prematurely, this was reported in the Console window in Workbench.

```
 -------------------
 Start Run Session
 Connected
 <<X3/Kernel/init.m
 Initialization Complete
 Running Test File: X3/Tests/UListTest.mt

 {Get::noopen}
 Error -> Exit
 End Session
 -------------------
```

The message {Get::noopen} occurs when you try to load a non-existing class. I would like to catch this in MUnit and report the testcase as failed.

Question:

#### How can I trap a situation like the one as described above ( i.e. something unexpected goes wrong ) in MUnit ? ( Deciding if it is an error or test failure should be handled programmatically in the test code. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are several parts here.

First, I set up a WB project to test your input, and while I do get the same error messages when running the unit test, I do not get the kernel hang - rather I either get the test to fail (if I do not wrap the test code in `Quiet` - see below for the explanation), or it exits prematurely (for the reason, also see below). But note that I changed the `oosys'` context name (also see below).

[image]

One thing to check is that in the WB project, your packages' contexts should be sub-contexts of the main context of your application. Therefore, `oosys'` becomes (in my case) `OOSystemTests'oosys'`. This should be reflected both in the package itself, and in the package imports (calls to `Needs` ets). For example, your version of `oosys` will start as `BeginPackage["OOSystemTests'oosys'"];` (change single quotes to context marks).

Next, one thing which is good to know is that messages produced during the run of the unit test are by default considered an error, so the test will fail. You can specify that the messages are expected, to avoid that (see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/tester/tester.html) page for details), or you can wrap your test code in `Quiet`). You should do either of this to get past through it, to the end of your test (I wrapped the test code in `Quiet`).

Once you do that, your test runs, but  `MUnit` reports that the kernel exits prematurely. And this brings us back to the application, `OO System`. To my mind, it does contain interesting ideas, but it falls short of being a professionally written mma extension package, on several grounds. First, the reason why it exits prematurely: if you look at `loadClass` implementation, you will notice the call to `checkClass` function, inside which you can see a number of calls to `Quit[]`. I don't know whether or not I should explain why this is a wrong way of doing it, but I've said quite a bit about  [mma error-reporting techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560116/best-practices-in-error-reporting-mathematica/6563886#6563886) before, and calling `Quit[]` inside a lower-level function is not listed there, for a reason. This is not even mma-specific: it is a standard wisdom in software engineering that the lower-level functions normally should not make decisions of the scale that only high-level functions address (such as exiting an application). Another place which I noticed upon a really superficial reading of the code is in the `newContext` function, where the `oosys'` context is listed explicitly as string (hard-coded), which means a possibility of breaking whenever the context name is changed (say, as in our case). The way debugging is organized also does not look very exciting to me. Perhaps, there are other things, I did not read very carefully.

I hope I gave enough pointers so that you can make it through the `MUnit` with the desirable outcome, perhaps modifying some of the OO System source code in the process (if its license allows that). In this regard, I would repeat an advice I already gave to you: if you want to use it really productively, read the code carefully, take the good ideas (which I am sure there are there), and implement your own object model in the way you want it, so that you control all the code.

Comment: I was wrong about the 'hang'. It was indeed a premature ending of MUnit. This looks promising. I'll go through your answer in detail this evening. Thank you very much.

Comment: My settings must be ok because I have been MUnit testing with oosys for a while. It is just this specific test where MUnit exits prematurely. This happens when I load a class which does not exist yet. -
Have you been able to let MUnit fail in this case? Or should the test been wrapped in Quiet[]? The entire test? Or just the creation of expected result? -

Comment: About oo system. It may not be perfect and I think the author has done a great job! Of course it is not perfect. The author is not actively maintaining it, I wrote him once but with no reply. There is no license, nor (c) in the file, I suppose we can interpret that as a donation. I will treat it as if it was licensed LGPL though. When and if my application has sufficient mass I'll digg into oosys. Currently I am developing util type of libraries for it.

Comment: @nilo de roock I can't get the test to fail, but I can get it to pass. MUnit is configured so that any error message (unless explicitly specified) leads to the premature exit of the kernel. Wrap your test code in `Quiet` like so: ` Quiet[clist = loadClass["UList"]]`. To see what is going on, set `MFDebug = True; ` in your `.mt` file before the test. You will see that now the kernel exit is due to the `checkClass` function. Comment it out in the source ('oosys') and your test will pass. To fail it, you can add code to analyze error messages, perhaps using `Check`.

Comment: @nilo de roock Specifically, if you: 1. Comment out `checkClass`, and 2. Use this code: `Quiet[Check[clist = loadClass["UList"],$Failed]]`, you will get your test to fail rather than kernel to exit prematurely. Regarding OO System, I have no doubts it has its merits, my point was not how good or bad it is, but how much of its code you *control*, in the sense of developed intuition and absence of nasty surprises. The difference between professionally-written packages and anything else is mainly that the former I *can* use as black boxes and be reasonably sure that I won't need to dig deeper.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments, advice Leonid.

Comment: @Leonid - Have you ever looked at or tried Objectica? The documentation is rather interesting and worth a look, IMO. Seems like they make heavy use of SubValues (from what I can tell). Also seems to be the case that one can develop code using Objectica and include it right along an authored package, so end users *don't* have to own Objectica too. (Of course it's pricey for pro users, but there's also a student license.)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 No, I have not tried. You may be right - it might be worth a try. But I would strongly prefer an open - source mma package, not even because of the money issue but because I want to control the code. This is important in this case, since I expect that every serious OO mma extension must overcome several hard problems, such as slow performance and the need for garbage collection. One of the things I wanted to do is to roll out my own OO mma extension, and include there those OO features I like and the way I like it, but it is hard to say if I ever find time for that :).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly, don't you just need to (1) move Class["UList`"] up to the evaluate part and (2) alter your expected output to {Get::noopen}?

Comment: @nilo - Cool blog...added to my RSS. I was just reading about K and kdb+. Have you seen Sal Mangano's presentation on kdb+ and Mathematica? (on Youtube)

Comment: Thank you, spread the word. ;-) - About Sal's video. No I have not seen it but I will try to find it.